# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: php, ссылки, маршрутизация, ресурсы, laravel-8

Имеется такой маршрут:

```
Route::get('/product/{id}',[MainController::class, 'product'])->name('product');
```

И такая разметка, вызывающая этот маршрут:

```
<a class="product_card_list_link_grid" href="{{route('product',['id'=> $product['id']])}}">
   <img class="product_card_list_image" src="assets/img/product/{{$product['image_product']}}" alt="{{$product['name_product']}}">
</a>
```

Метод контроллера, который отображает представление:

```
    public function product($id)
    {
        $array_select_product = Product::where('products.id', '=', $id)->join('distributors', 'distributors.id', '=', 'products.distributor_id')->join('genres', 'genres.id', '=', 'products.genre_id')->get(['products.*', 'distributors.image_distributor', 'genres.name_genre']);
        return view('product', [
            'array_select_product' => $array_select_product
        ]);
    }
```

И вроде все хорошо, страницу открывает, данные из бд выводит, но стили, картинки, скрипты, в общем все ресурсы не загружаются. При этом если изменить маршрут на такой:

```
Route::get('/{id}',[MainController::class, 'product'])->name('product');
```

А вызывать его так:

```
<a class="product_card_list_link_grid" href="/$product['id']">
```

То все отлично работает.
Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема и как мне ее исправить. А так же если есть другие ошибки укажите на них.

Comment: Может другой какой маршрут совпадает перед указанным ...

Comment: Вы передаете данные во вьюшку через array_select_product, а пытаетесь использовать product переменную, которая там не известна.

Comment: @Daniel Protopopov
Я не стал вставлять весь код, который не относится к делу. Данные выводятся нормально из этого массива, product это ключ у foreach, проблема именно в маршруте.

Comment: @Roman Grinyov
Нет, совпадающих маршрутов нет. Да и я бы его точно заметил и исправил, так как у меня их всего 3шт. )))

Comment: @Cr1ppi Попробуйте зайти на отрисованную страницу и посмотреть в коде оной страницы пути к стилям/пикчам, скопируйте и попробуйте перейти, если не получится, то дело в ассетах, возможно их нужно проинсталлировать. Я предполагаю, что по `/{id}` роуту вы натыкаетесь на уже сгенерированные, а на новом их попросту нет. Не силен в Laravel, но предполагаю, что можно сделать что-то php ... assetic:watch -vv, будет в реалтайме их отслеживать (вроде вот: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#watching-assets-for-changes).

Answer (score 0):

В общем, я нашел решение своей проблемы, нужно было ссылки на ресурсы писать так:

```
<img class="logo_image" src="{{URL::asset('assets/img/joystick_game_3819.ico')}}" alt="Logo">
```

А я писал так:

```
<img class="logo_image" src="assets/img/joystick_game_3819.ico" alt="Logo">
```

Это относится ко всем подключаемым ресурсам.

Answer (score 0):

Не ответ на вопрос.
Но хотел бы дать совет про реализацию кода который касается запросов к базе данных, и не только.

1. Зачем использовать `join` ? Если в `laravel` есть возможность отношений (`relationship`).
2. Работать напрямую с базой данных в контроллерах очень плохой пример кода.

Код надо делиь как минимум на 3 части.

1. В контроллерах нужно оставить только бизнес логику приложения.
2. Для работы с базой данных, из хороших подходов можно взять например `repository`. Вот [пример](https://laravel.demiart.ru/repository-design-pattern/) для реализации кода с помощю репозиториев. Можете погуглить, там найдете все что нужно.
3. Для остальных монипуляций кода можно использовать сервисы. Тоесть та логика кода, который не относиться к базе данных и к бизнес логике приложения.
4. Всегда делите код на мелкие части. Что бы потом можно было легче разобрать код. И можно было повторно использовать код там где этому будет нужда.